# canvas indexsizeerror drawImage

Tags: javascript, canvas

I have a problem with my drawImage.
I don't understand why i have a indexSizeError because all my values aren't negatives or not greaters than the config of my canvas.
The senario:
I have a canvas where there is a picture with a square to capture a part of the picture.
when i chose the part, i click on a button and call this function :

```
this.reset();
firstDraw = false;
var fact = w / imgW; //facteur de l'image réelle à celle affiché pour rendre proportionnel le carré
var newC = Math.floor(c * fact);
canvasCrop = this.element.dom.firstChild;

this.canvasCrop = canvasCrop;
canvasCrop.setAttribute("width", 300);
canvasCrop.setAttribute("height", 300);
this.context = canvasCrop.getContext("2d");
this.context.fillStyle = this.brushColor;


this.context.drawImage(photo, Math.floor((x - xDecal) * fact), Math.floor((y - yDecal) * fact), newC, newC, 0, 0, newC, newC);
//assigne à imgCorp l'image capturée
imgCrop.setSrc(canvasCrop.toDataURL());
```

and i have index size error with drawImage...

see the variables values :

```
Math.floor((x - xDecal) * fact)  : 183
Math.floor((y - yDecal) *  fact) : 283
newC                             : 161
photo.naturalWidth               : 372
photo.naturalHeight              : 140
this.canvasCrop.width            : 300
this.canvasCrop.height           : 300
xDecal                           : 16.42296072507554
yDecal                           : 0
x                                : 187
y                                : 263
```

Comment: is your photo variable defined?

Comment: yes the photo is defined : photo : img sencha-large.png and it's class is Image.

Comment: it's good i find my error it's because i say to clip the photo on yStart of 283 whereas the picture have 140 of heigth... stupid error...2 days for that!!! grrr but thank as well :)

Comment: Not a problem mate :) Glad to hear you fixed it.